# Symfony security component - Unable to find key \"username\" in the token payload

Tags: php, api, symfony, security, authentication

With this configuration listed below I've experienced some weird issue I cannot resolve alone since i'm too new in Symfony.

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Api\User\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        users:
            id: 'App\Api\Auth\Provider\AuthProvider'
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        # Api will be stateless, a token will be generated
        api_login:
            pattern: /api/login
            stateless: true
            context: api
            anonymous: true
            provider: users
            form_login:
                check_path: /api/login
                username_parameter: email
                password_parameter: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
        # For web calls no need to be stateless
        web_login:
            pattern: /login
            stateless: false
            context: web
            anonymous: true
            provider: users
            guard:
              entry_point: 'App\User\Auth\Guard\LoginAuthenticator'
              authenticators:
                - 'App\Api\Auth\Guard\LoginAuthenticator'
            form_login:
              login_path: /login
              check_path: /login
        api:
            provider: users
            context: api
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        web:
            provider: users
            context: web
            pattern: ^(/user|/template)
            stateless: false
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - 'App\Api\Auth\Guard\LoginAuthenticator'
        main:
            pattern:  ^/
            anonymous: ~
            logout:
              path: /logout
              target: /login



    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/user/*, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I've :

- A back office with secured area with stateful mode
- An API with secured area with stateless mode (JWT token)

Now Here what is working :

- I can connect with my HTML form and see my roles and my data (email)
- When I'm connected (HTML) I'm instantly redirect on /user/profile
  endpoint and see my informations
- I can call my API login endpoint and get the JWT token

Here what's not working

- From API call, I've a token that have no username (null) in it
- If y try to access on secured area from api I got an error listed
  below

My decoded token :

> ```
> {"alg":"RS256"}{"roles":["ROLE_USER"],"username":null,"iat":1527787676,"exp":1527791276}
> ```

The error:

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Unable to find key \"username\" in the token payload."
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My identity field is email, not username.

In the jwt config file I just have to put this :

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/%env(JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)%'
    public_key_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/%env(JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    user_identity_field: email #this line
```