# Since lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle 2.16: The "lexik_jwt_authentication.user_identity_field" configuration key is deprecated

Tags: symfony, jwt

I have just upgrade [`lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle`](https://packagist.org/packages/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle) from `v2.16.0`  to version `3.x-dev` because I had this error [Fatal error Cannot declare trait ForwardCompatAuthenticatorTrait](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/996), and upgrading to version `3.x-dev` fix the error.

Now I have a deprecation message:

```
deprecation.INFO: User Deprecated: Since lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle 2.16: The "lexik_jwt_authentication.user_identity_field" configuration key is deprecated since version 2.16, implement "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getUserIdentifier()" instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle 2.16: The \"lexik_jwt_authentication.user_identity_field\" configuration key is deprecated since version 2.16, implement \"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\User\\UserInterface::getUserIdentifier()\" instead. at /srv/api/vendor/symfony/config/Definition/ArrayNode.php:241)"} []
```

Here is my configuration:

```yaml
# api/config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 604800 # 1 week
    user_identity_field: email # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629890/symfony-security-component-unable-to-find-key-username-in-the-token-payloa/50630492
```

I know that I have to remove `user_identity_field` but when I remove it I got error:
`{"code":401,"message":"Unable to find key \u0022username\u0022 in the token payload."}`. `username` is the default `user_identity_field` value.

How can I fix this ?

Also my `security.yml`:

```yaml
# api/config/packages/security.yaml
security:
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
  password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'

  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User

  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    api:
      # https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/
      # https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/doc/index.md#configuration
      pattern: ^/api/
      stateless: true
      provider: app_user_provider
      jwt: ~
      switch_user: { parameter: X-Switch-User }
    login:
      stateless: true
      json_login:
        check_path: /authentication-token
        success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        
    # ...
```

In `api/src/Entity/User.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Utils\StringLengthUtils;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[Table(name: 'user_t')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Id]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, length: StringLengthUtils::MAX_LENGTH, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    // other properties ...

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    // other getter and setters ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `user_identity_field` parameter, you need to use `username_path`

```
login:
  stateless: true
  json_login:
    username_path: email
    check_path: /authentication-token
    success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
    failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```